# understanding levels: is levels not same as unique()

Tags: r

I read a csv file into a data frame named `rr`. The character column was treated as factors which was nice.

Do I understand correctly that the `levels` are just the `unique` values of the columns? i.e.

```
levels(rr$col) == unique(rr$col)
```

Then I wanted to strip leading and trailing whitespaces.(I didn't knew about strip.WHITESPACE option in read) 
So I did

```
rr$col = str_trim(rr$col).
```

Now the `rr$col` is no longer a factor. So I did

```
rr$col = as.factor(rr$col)
```

But I see now that `levels(rr$col)` is missing some unique values !! Why?

Comment: The `str_trim` converts it to character column.  It is not clear how the levels got missing after the `str_trim`.  Please provide some reproducible example. `v1 <- factor(c(' ab', 'ac ', ' ab', 'ac ')); levels(v1)#[1] " ab" "ac "; v2 <- factor(str_trim(v1)); levels(v2)#[1] "ab" "ac"`

Comment: But if `v1 <- factor(c(' ab', 'ac ', ' ab', ' ac '))` Then, you may find a difference in levels after conversion

Comment: `levels(rr$col)` is not necessarily the same as `unique(rr$col)`. `factor` variables can have factor levels that are not present in the data but defined as factor levels. `unique` applied to a character vector will only show the unique values that are actually present in the data.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I think the `rr` is not a subset of main dataset based on OP's post

Comment: Sorry I forgot there was a filter there in as well.Now I understand that levels can be different than unique. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

"Level" is a special property of a variable (column). They are handy because they are retained even if a subset does not contain any values from a specific level. Take for example

```
x <- as.factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 3))
```

If we subset only elements under levels `a` and `b`, `c` is left out. It will be detected with `levels()`, but not `unique()`. The latter will see which values appear in the subset only.

```
> x[c(1,2, 4)]
[1] a a b
Levels: a b c
> levels(x[c(1,2, 4)])
[1] "a" "b" "c"
> unique(x[c(1,2, 4)])
[1] a b
Levels: a b c
```

Comment: I am interested in the question as it is expressed in the title. ;) Is there a difference between `unique()` and `levels()` and when should I use one of them?

Comment: @buhz To reiterate, if you have a factor vector `c("a", "a", "b", "c")` and remove both `"a"`, you will get `c("b", "c")`. This corresponds to what you get with `unique()`, but `levels()` will still be `a b c` because R remembers it had `a` before one removed it. To lose `a`, you have to run `droplevels`.